# Migrating SQL Server 2008 tables to SQL Server CE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I used SQL Server Migration Assistant to migrate a MySQL database to SQL Server 2008. I am looking for a way to move the migrated SQL Server tables to SQL Server CE, but there is no such option in the Migration Assistant. How to copy or move the migrated tables to SQL Server CE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my command line utiltiy Export2sqlce, as described here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html